# How do I redirect output of echo command in bash script to script's directory?

Tags: bash, output, dirname

Fairly simple, I have an `echo` statement in my shell (bash) script that I want to redirect to an external file as a means of logging. The script is run by the root user's crontab every hour (via `sudo crontab -e`).

I want this log file to reside in the same directory as the script.

My first attempt was,

```
echo "$(date) | blah blah" >> "$(pwd)/script.log"
```

However, this clearly does not work as the working directory of the root crontab (`/root/`) is not the same as the directory of the script. So following some advice on SO I did instead,

```
script_dir=$(dirname $0)
echo "$(date) | blah blah" >> "$(script_dir)/script.log"
```

This time, for reasons I do not yet understand, the log file is saved under `/`, as in `/script.log`.

Logically one would assume that the variable `script_dir` was evaluated to an empty string and so `"$(script_dir)/script.log"` was evaluated as `"/script.log"`.

But as a test, I wrote a simple test script,

```
echo "$(dirname $0)"
```

and ran it from `/`. Sure enough, I get a proper non-empty output: `/home/pi/scripts/testscripts/dirname.sh` (where the test script I wrote resides).

So what's the deal, and how do I get this to work?

---

*p.s. `bash --version` says I am currently running GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release*

Comment: BTW, what is your intention of doing `echo "$(date) | blah blah"` which makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Inian My script restarts my raspberry pi with `shutdown -r now` whenever it loses internet connection, which I determine by looking at the exit code of a `ping` command in an `if` conditional. I want to have a log of when this happens. The full `echo` statement is actually `"$(date +"%d %b %r") | $(uptime -p) | Exit ${code}. Restarting..."`.

Comment: fair enough! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the curly braces within double-quotes to expand variables in `bash`, something like,

```
echo "$(date) | blah blah" >> "${script_dir}/script.log"
```

> [`Shell Parameter Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
>
> The ‘$’ character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion.
>
> *The basic form of parameter expansion is ${parameter}*. The value of parameter is substituted. The braces are required when parameter is a positional parameter with more than one digit, or when parameter is followed by a character that is not to be interpreted as part of its name.

---

[**More on Parameter expansion**](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#simple_usage)

```
${PARAMETER}
```

The easiest form is to just use a parameter's name within braces. This is identical to using `$FOO` like you see it everywhere, but has the advantage that it can be immediately followed by characters that would be interpreted as part of the parameter name otherwise. Compare these two expressions (WORD="car" for example), where we want to print a word with a trailing "s":

```
echo "The plural of $WORD is most likely $WORDs"
echo "The plural of $WORD is most likely ${WORD}s"
```

Why does the first one fail? It prints nothing, because a parameter (variable) named "WORDs" is undefined and thus printed as "" (nothing). Without using braces for parameter expansion, Bash will interpret the sequence of all valid characters from the introducing "$" up to the last valid character as name of the parameter. When using braces you just force Bash to only interpret the name inside your braces.

Answer (score 1):

This line has an error :

```
echo "$(date) | blah blah" >> "$(script_dir)/script.log"
```

It should be :

```
echo "$(date) | blah blah" >> "$script_dir/script.log"
```

The `"$(script_dir)"` syntax tries to execute a command named `script_dir` and capture its output to use as a value inside the string.  What you need is a simple variable expansion, `$script_dir`, which simply extracts the value of a variable named script_dir.